# Laravel can't read a "recently" created cookie

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cookies

I have a project who authenticate the user using cookies like `token_` and `refreshToken_`, and a middleware who intercept my routes and verify if the user is logged or not.
In my middleware, when i need to renew the `token_` I have the following code:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware\VerifyAccessToken

$cookie_name = "token_";
$cookie_value = $obj->access_token;
$expires_in = $obj->expires_in;
$time = time() + $expires_in; // 3600 = 1 hora
$path = "/";
$domain = env('COOKIE_DOMAIN');
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $time, $path, $domain, false, true);

$cookie_name = "refreshToken_";
$cookie_value = $obj->refresh_token;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $time + 3600, $path, $domain, false, true);

return $next($request);
```

It works apparently fine, but the problem is:
After the middleware intercep my route and renew the cookie, the request proced to his controller, but there, I can't access the cookie using `$_COOKIE['token_']` and I get an error, but if I look in the chrome's inspector, the cookie is there and reloading the page (F5) I can access the cookie in controller
Have a method for me access the cookie in controller without need to go to the view before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't set PHP cookie on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455214/cant-set-php-cookie-on-the-same-page)

Comment: laravel handles cookies differently, retrieving a cookie is $value = $request->cookie('name');

Comment: See also for a Laravel-specific answer/approach, particularly the "Laravel does support in-memory retrieval of cookies via queued()" bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836332/set-and-check-cookie-in-the-one-response-laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the value of Cookie in Laravel, do you need to use:

```
$token = Cookie::queued('token_');
dd($token->getValue());
```

https://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Cookie.html